# Why does the ngModelCtrl.$valid not update?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm trying to create a directive that contains an inputfield with a ng-model and knows if the inputcontrol is valid. (I want to change a class on a label within the directive based on this state.) I want to use the ngModelController.$valid to check this, but it always returns true.

formcontroller.$valid or formcontroller.inputfieldname.$valid do work as exprected, but since im trying to build a reusable component using a formcontroller is not very handy because then i have to determine what field of the form corresponds with the current directive.

I dont understand why one works and one doesnt, because in de angular source it seems to be the same code that should manage these states: The ngModelController.$setValidity function.

I created a test directive that contains a numeric field with required and a min value. As you can see in the fiddle below, the model controller is only triggered during page load and after that never changes.

[jsfiddle with example directive](http://jsfiddle.net/2yu6p/)

Directive code:

```
angular.module('ui.directives', []).directive('textboxValid',
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['ngModel', '^form'],
        scope: {            
            ngModel: '='
        },
        template: '<input  type="number" required name="somefield" min="3" ng-model="ngModel" /> '+
          '<br>Form controller $valid: {{formfieldvalid}} <br> ' + 
          'Model controller $valid: {{modelvalid}} <br>'+
          'Form controller $valid: {{formvalid}} <br>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
            var ngModelCtrl = controllers[0];
            var formCtrl = controllers[1];

            function modelvalid(){ 
                return ngModelCtrl.$valid;
            }

            function formvalid(){ 
                return formCtrl.$valid;
            }

            scope.$watch(formvalid, function(newVal,oldVal)
            {
                scope.modelvalid = ngModelCtrl.$valid;
                scope.formvalid = formCtrl.$valid;
                scope.formfieldvalid = formCtrl.somefield.$valid;
            });

            scope.$watch(modelvalid, function(newVal,oldVal)
            {
                scope.modelvalid = ngModelCtrl.$valid;
                scope.formvalid = formCtrl.$valid;
                scope.formfieldvalid = formCtrl.somefield.$valid;           
                //This one only gets triggered on pageload
                alert('modelvalid ' + newVal );
            });
        }


    };
    }
  );
```

Can someone help me understand this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out..

The textboxValid directive has a ng-model directive, and so does the input that gets created by the directive template. However, these are two different directives, both with their own seperate controller.

So, i changed my solution to use an attribute directive like below. This works as expected.

```
.directive('attributetest',
    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {            
            ngModel: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            function modelvalid(){ 
                 return ngModelCtrl.$valid;
            }

        scope.$watch(modelvalid, function(newVal,oldVal){
                console.log('scope.modelvalid = ' + ngModelCtrl.$valid );
            });     

        }       

    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because you're watching a function and the $watch is only execute when this function is called !!

Watch the model instead like that :

```
scope.$watch('ngModel', function(newVal,oldVal)
            {
                scope.modelvalid = ngModelCtrl.$valid;
                scope.formvalid = formCtrl.$valid;
                scope.formfieldvalid = formCtrl.somefield.$valid;           
                //This one triggered each time the model changes
                alert('modelvalid ' + ngModelCtrl.$valid );
            });
```

Comment: The watch is not the problem, if you try the code on the jsfiddle you will see that the watch on formCtrl.$valid does work. The $valid state of the modelCtrl just doesnt change. 

Also, ngModel only changes when the current input in the control is valid, so watching it will not help. Any other ideas?